# Rework type definitions for analytics-node

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-definitions

There are type definitions for that library that exposes the class `Analytics`

So, sources are the next

```
class Analytics {}

module.exports = Analytics
```

Types definitions are good, shortly they are

```
declare namespace AnalyticsNode {
  export class Analytics {}
}

export = AnalyticsNode.Analytics
```

But after those declarations the only way to use library is with

```
import Analytics = require('analytics-node')
```

How can I override types definitions locally to make them work in ES6 import way?

I tried to declare a module

```
declare module 'analytics-node' {
  // export default
  // export
  // export = 
}
```

But this doesn't work. (`import * as Analytics from 'analytics-node'` gets access to function, but no `new Analytics` raises an error in compiler)

I tried to follow guideline about [module class definitions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-class-d-ts.html) but without luck.

Comment: I have the same problem.  The type definitions export the `Analytics` _class_, but not the _interfaces_ that are used within the method signatures of the class (e.g. `AnalyticsNode.Data` and `AnalyticsNode.Integrations`).  I'd like to _extend_ the `Analytics` class to provide my own implementation of `track()`, but doing so requires dumbing down the parameter types unnecessarily in typescript.

Comment: Did either of you find a solution?

Comment: @sabrehagen I just posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is in differences between CommonJS(node) and ES implementation of modules.

There is a flag in TS `esModuleInterop` that nullifies the difference between the two systems. With that flag, it's possible to have something like `import module from 'module'` instead of `import * as module from 'module'`

Here is a note from [github issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/23760#issuecomment-412740028) by **Andrew Fong**.

> absent esModuleInterop, the only way to use that syntax is for analytics-node to move to a default ES module export. Here's the thing though -- unless Node itself forces a migration to ES modules, the CommonJS single export remains perfectly valid. There technically isn't anything to fix. esModuleInterop isn't a hacky workaround. It's actually how, AFAICT, the TS devs want us to type these scenarios.